# Having trouble with referencing c# project from web forms project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to write a page that displays a flow Diagram to the user. I downloaded the Tree Chart Generator from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20508/Tree-Chart-Generator and added the Tree Generator project to my solution. However, when I try to reference TreeGenerator from my code behind, it is not recognized. I am sorry if this is a simplistic question, I am pretty new to .NET development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your web site project in the Solution Explorer, right click, click Add Reference, and select the project you want to reference. You may need to change to a "Solution" tab depending on your version of Visual Studio. I'm assuming Visual Studio because you didn't provide that detail in your question.

Comment: Thanks so much. So simple yet so hard.